# how to assign my json data to highchart, Below is my json data

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

[{"country":"india","year":1880,"population":2000000},{"country":"asia","year":1880,"population":2000000},{"country":"africa","year":1880,"population":100000},{"country":"america","year":1880,"population":150000},{"country":"europe","year":1880,"population":1500000},{"country":"oceania","year":1880,"population":1200000},{"country":"asia","year":1900,"population":3000000},{"country":"africa","year":1900,"population":2500000},{"country":"america","year":1900,"population":2304000},{"country":"europe","year":1900,"population":1304000},{"country":"oceania","year":1900,"population":2304500},{"country":"oceania","year":2013,"population":4000000},{"country":"asia","year":2013,"population":6000000},{"country":"africa","year":2013,"population":8000000},{"country":"america","year":2013,"population":5050000},{"country":"europe","year":2013,"population":6800000}]

i want to know how to assign the above json data to series in highchart to plot graph dynamically

mY client side script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
      option={
         chart:{
             renderTo: 'chart_div',
                type: 'bar',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
          },
          title: {
                text: 'Continent vs. Population',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            xAxis:{
                categories:[],
            },
            yAxis:{
                min:0,
                title: {
                    text: 'country'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                 data:[],
                 name:[]
            }]
      };
      $.getJSON("graph.htm",function(json){

         for(var count=0;count<json.length;count++){
            var  row=json[count];
            renderData(row);
                 }
       });
      function renderData(row){
          alert(row.population);
          option.xAxis.categories=row.country;

          option.series.data=row.population;
          option.series.name = row.year;
          chart = new Highcharts.Chart(option);
      }; 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: A bit of research wouldn't cause you any harm: http://www.highcharts.com/demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: in the function(data) there are several data like country ,year and population so i need to differentiate and assign in series to DATA, NAMES and CATEGORIES.

Comment: i am unable to plot graphs can i have any sample example with backend code please.

Comment: thanks for comment bjb568 can i know how to assign catageries in graph